# Updating task queue of appengine application via cloud build fails with PERMISSION_DENIED

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-build

I have a simple cloud build pipeline that updates the task queue of an appengine application via `gcloud app deploy backend/src/main/config/queue.yaml`. This fails with the following log ouput:

```
descriptor:      [/workspace/backend/src/main/config/queue.yaml]
type:            [task queues]
target project:  [<project>]


ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) PERMISSION_DENIED: The caller does not have permission
```

I already assigned the following roles to the cloudbuild service account `...@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com` of the project.

```
roles/appengine.appAdmin
roles/cloudtasks.admin
roles/cloudtasks.queueAdmin
```

Any ideas what i´m missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a similar issue on the [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/137078982#comment4). It seems as you only need to add an extra permission `roles/serviceusage.serviceUsageViewer` and it should work.